# What's the name of these "banners" used in Japanese restaurants?

Tags: nouns

What's the name of these "banners" used in Japanese restaurants?

I'm interested in both Japanese name and English name (closest approximation).

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I'd call them "banners".  Hard to be any more specific without knowing what they say/signify.  (Although if they covered the top edge of the windows, and especially if a part of a curtain system, then they might be viewed as comprising a "valance".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Japanese, it's called a *noren* (written [暖簾](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9A%96%E7%B0%BE) in Japanese orthography).

English doesn't have a common term for *noren*, so the word has been borrowed into English, but if you use it in English you'll probably have to define it so your audience knows what you mean.  You can see this sort of use on [the English Wikipedia page for *noren*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noren):

> Noren (暖簾) are traditional Japanese fabric dividers, hung between rooms, on walls, in doorways, or in windows. They usually have one or more vertical slits cut from the bottom to nearly the top of the fabric, allowing for easier passage or viewing. Noren are rectangular and come in many different materials, sizes, colors, and patterns.

Since the loanword *noren* isn't known to most English speakers, phrases like *shop curtain* or *noren curtain* are sometimes used in English instead, but unless the reader is familiar with the type of curtain you're talking about, it's likely to be unclear without further explanation.

You can see more examples of what qualify as *noren* in [a Google Image Search for 暖簾](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%9A%96%E7%B0%BE&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 1):

This specific example you gave is a **“restaurant menu”** from the Kukuru restaurant in Osaka Japan.  Or, basically they are *“signs”*, or *“signage”* in English.  (or as you simply state, *"banners"*.)

**[Menu](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/menu?s=t)** - 1.) a list of the dishes served at a meal; bill of fare:  2.) the dishes served.

**[Sign](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sign?s=t)** - 5.) a notice, bearing a name, direction, warning, or advertisement, that is displayed or posted for public view:

Comment: The OP asked about the **object**, not the text/symbols *on the object*. Calling these pieces of cloth "menus" does not answer the question about what the objects are called, and calling them "signs" is too vague. In English we have many words for signs (*billboards*, *marquees*, *placards*, *banners*) each of which conjures up a specific image of a physical object without concern for what is written on them. As posted by @snailboat above these objects are called "noren" and the fact that the particular noren pictured are being used to display menu items is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @O.M.Y. - yeah, unless this is an _English language_ board; defining for people what _English language_ speakers would use for such a sign.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for "**both** *Japanese name and English name (closest approximation).*"

The Japanese name is **"*noren*"** (as answered quite well by @snailboat).

As for the "closest approximation" in English the answer is in fact {...pause for drumroll...} [**"*banner*"**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banner)*!* -- "*a sign painted on cloth and hung over a street, entrance, etc.*".

The word **"*sign*"** is technically correct but is not the "closest" as it is a far more generic word (note that *sign* is used in the definition of the more precise word *banner*.)